# Different search term on different fields using edismax query parser in solr

Tags: solr, edismax

I have a solr query that searches on multiple fields. To increase the recall, I also do wildcard and fuzzy query. I use edismax query parser because I also have to use boost function.

Here is the relevant parts of the query:

```
defType=edismax&q= (wine AND company) OR  (wine* AND company*)^0.5  OR (wine* OR company*)^0.01 OR (wine~1 AND company~1)^0.02&qf=primary_tags^1 secondary_tags_s^0.2 merchant_name_s^0.5
```

Now, the above query searches for `(wine AND company) OR  (wine* AND company*)^0.5  OR (wine* OR company*)^0.01 OR (wine~1 AND company~1)^0.02` on all the fields `primary_tags^1 secondary_tags_s^0.2 merchant_name_s^0.5`, but what I want is that `(wine AND company)` should only be searched on `merchant_name_s^0.5`, `(wine* AND company*)^0.5  OR (wine* OR company*)^0.01` on `primary_tags^1` and `(wine~1 AND company~1)^0.02` on `secondary_tags_s^0.2`.

What would be the correct way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

edismax [supports the full Lucene syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html).

```
q=merchant_name:(wine AND company)^0.5 primary_tags:(wine* AND company*)^0.5 primary_tags:(wine* OR company*)^0.01 secondary_tags_s:(wine~1 AND company~1)^0.0004
```

should be about the same query you've described. I've combined the `secondary_tags_s` part into one single weight and seprated the `primary_tags` clauses, since the default behavior is `OR` between the terms anyway (depending on `q.op`).